# Is async and await exclusively for GUI-based asynchronous programming?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I've been reading about the new `async` and `await` operators in C# and tried to figure out in which circumstances they would possibly be useful to me. I studied several MSDN articles and here's what I read between the lines:

You can use `async` for Windows Forms and WPF event handlers, so they can perform lengthy tasks without blocking the UI thread while the bulk of the operation is being executed.

```
async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // even though this call takes a while, the UI thread will not block
    // while it is executing, therefore allowing further event handlers to
    // be invoked.
    await SomeLengthyOperationAsync();
}
```

A method using `await` must be `async`, which means that the usage of any `async` function somewhere in your code ultimately forces all methods in the calling sequence from the UI event handlers up until the lowest-level `async` method to be `async` as well.

In other words, if you create a thread with an ordinary good old `ThreadStart` entry point (or a Console application with good old `static int Main(string[] args)`), then you cannot use `async` and `await` because at one point you would have to use `await`, and make the method that uses it `async`, and hence in the calling method you also have to use `await` and make that one `async` and so on. But once you reach the thread entry point (or `Main()`), there's no caller to which an `await` would yield control to.

So basically you cannot use `async` and `await` without having a GUI that uses the standard WinForms and WPF message loop. I guess all that makes indeed sense, since MSDN states that `async` programming does not mean multithreading, but using the UI thread's spare time instead; when using a console application or a thread with a user defined entry point, multithreading would be necessary to perform asynchronous operations (if not using a compatible message loop).

My question is, are these assumptions accurate?

Comment: +1 for a good question, even if it's completely misinterpreted the documentation :)

Comment: See some non GUI examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> So basically you cannot use async and await without having a GUI that uses the standard WinForms and WPF message loop.

That's absolutely *not* the case.

In Windows Forms and WPF, `async`/`await` has the handy property of coming back to the UI thread when the asynchronous operation you were awaiting has completed, but that doesn't mean that's the only purpose to it.

If an asynchronous method executes on a thread-pool thread - e.g. in a web service - then the continuation (the rest of the asynchronous method) will simply execute in *any* thread-pool thread, with the context (security etc) preserved appropriately. This is still really useful for keeping the number of threads down.

For example, suppose you have a high traffic web service which mostly proxies requests to other web services. It spends most of its time waiting for other things, whether that's due to network traffic or genuine time at another service (e.g. a datbase). You shouldn't need lots of threads for that - but with blocking calls, you naturally end up with a thread per request. With async/await, you'd end up with very few threads, because very few requests would actually need any work performed for them at any one point in time, even if there were a *lot* of requests "in flight".

The trouble is that async/await is most easily *demonstrated* with UI code, because everyone knows the pain of either using background threads properly or doing too much work in the UI thread. That doesn't mean it's the only place the feature is useful though - far from it.

Various server-side technologies (MVC and WCF for example) already have support for asynchronous methods, and I'd expect others to follow suit.

Comment: Now that I've read all answers, I think I know where I went wrong. What I got right is that it's basically regular callback-based programming, but with better code. I assumed the `await` magic uses something strictly GUI-related to know where to invoke the callback (i.e. the remainder of the method after the `await`), when instead it uses `SynchronizationContext.Current`, `TaskScheduler.Current`, and "anything the OS deems appropriate" e.g. the ThreadPool, prioritized in that order. Unfortunately I'm that kind of person who's not comfortable using something I couldn't program myself.

Comment: @dialer: There's nothing wrong with wanting to peer behind the magic. You may like my Eduasync blog series: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx

Comment: Updated link for the start of the Eduasync series (the other link wasn't working for me): http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction/

Answer (score 8):

> A method using await must be async, which means that the usage of any async function somewhere in your code ultimately forces all methods in the calling sequence from the UI event handlers up until the lowest-level async method to be async as well.

Not true - methods marked async just mean they can use await, but callers of those methods have no restrictions.  If the method returns `Task` or `Task<T>` then they can use `ContinueWith` or anything else you could do with tasks in 4.0

A good non-UI example is MVC4 AsyncController.

Ultimately, async/await is mostly about getting the compiler rewriting so you can write what looks like synchronous code and avoid all the callbacks like you had to do before async/await was added. It also helps with the SynchronizationContext handling, useful for scenarios with thread affinity (UI frameworks, ASP.NET), but even without those, it's still useful.  Main can always do `DoStuffAsync().Wait();` for instance. :)

Answer (score 7):

> My question is, are these assumptions accurate?

No.

> You can use async for Windows Forms and WPF event handlers, so they can perform lengthy tasks without blocking the UI thread while the bulk of the operation is being executed.

True. Also true for other UI applications including Silverlight and Windows Store.

And *also* true for ASP.NET. In this case, it's the *HTTP request* thread that is not blocked.

> A method using await must be async, which means that the usage of any async function somewhere in your code ultimately forces all methods in the calling sequence from the UI event handlers up until the lowest-level async method to be async as well.

This is a best practice ("`async` all the way down"), but it's not strictly required. You *can* block on the result of an asynchronous operation; many people choose to do this in Console applications.

> an ordinary good old ThreadStart entry point

Well... I do have to take issue with "ordinary good old". As I explain on my blog, [`Thread` is pretty much the *worst* option you have for doing background operations](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html).

I recommend you review my [introduction to `async` and `await`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), and follow up with the [`async` / `await` FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1. async-await is only wrapper for Task class manipulations, which is part of so named Tasks Parallel Library - TPL(published before async-await auto code generation tech.)
2. So fact is you may not use any references to UI controls within async - await.
3. Typically async-await is powerfull tool for any web and server relations, loading resources, sql. It works with smart waiting data with alive UI.
4. Typically TPL application: from simple big size loop till multi stages parallel calculations in complex calculations based on shared data (ContinueWith and so on)