# Background worker not starting

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I've implemented a background worker onLoad of my window. The code in the Progress_Load is reached but after that the DoWork function is not called. The function excel.Read() reads a quite big excel tabel into a list, this takes about 1.5 min and that's why i want to do it a-syn.

```
public List<Part> partList = new List<Part>() { };
//boolean that will be set when the backgroundworker is done
public bool listRead = false;

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _Excel excel = new _Excel();
    partList = excel.Read();
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Message m;
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        m = new Message("The operation has been canceld!", "Canceled");
        this.Close();
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Error er = new Error("Error: " + e.Error.Message, "Error!");
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        listRead = true;
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    //Set the text.
    this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}

private void Progress_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (backgroundWorker1 == null)
    {
        backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any exceptions being thrown in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork()`?

Comment: maybe you get an exception somewhere? try to add `if( (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)`

Comment: Is `backgroundWorker1 == null` when `Progress_Load` is reached? The name sounds like a generated variable from the Designer. If the designer has created the object, it is not null

Comment: @ThomasWeller no the backgroundWorker1 is not null when Progress_Load is reached

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes that code is never reached it goes tough everything in Load and then remains in the main thread.

Comment: @TJasinski first of all, you don't need BGW at all. It's an obsolete class fully replaced by Task.Run, async/await and IProgress. Second, what is `_Excel` ? An Excel interop object perhaps? Office interop is essentially COM Automation, which is thread-sensitive. You can use the Open XML SDK or libraries like Epplus and ExcelDataReader to work with Excel files without actually installing Excell

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _Excel is my horrible naming convention. Thanks for the tip i will look into that!

Comment: @TJasinski but what *is* this thing? What does `excel.Read` do and why does it need to run in the background? If it uses Excel Interop, it could be slow simply because each cell access is a cross-process operation. How big is that big Excel table?

Comment: Its a class with 2 methods 1 to read the excel table ( which is 40 colums and 700+ rows ) and one to clean the open com objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's not null when loading the form. You may have added the BackgroundWorker via the designer. If so it's never null, you can hook up the event handlers also from its Properties/Events.

Try this

```
private void Progress_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (backgroundWorker1 == null)
    {
        backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    }

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

In WPF `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, workAction);` is a another option because report progress is not much useful in your scenario.  Here [example for Dispatcher and Background worker comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207832/wpf-dispatcher-begininvoke-and-ui-background-threads).

Comment: Although ideally if the background worker was added via the designer, the OP should also use the designer to hook up the event handlers.